# Paperplane html to pdf generator to generate pdf from local html pages

Tags: api

I am using [Paperplane API](https://www.paperplane.app) with Perl to create pdf from HTML pages. The problem is Paperplane requires a URL to create its PDF but I have HTML files available in a local directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried Paper Plane, but the first thing I try for these situations is a `file://` URL, such as `file:///Users/brian/Desktop/foo.html`. I don't expect most things to support it, but sometimes I am surprised. This won't work if a remote service does this for you, but may work for hosted services.

The next step I try is a mini local web server. You can [do that with Mojolicious](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Static), but many other things can do it too. It doesn't have to be a Perl thing.

Neither of those are going to work because something remote is going to be able to connect to your local machine, most likely. That still leaves the possibility of a public-facing server somehow. [Paperplane has a guide to  protecting documents](https://docs.paperplane.app/guide-securing-access-to-html-documents) if you go that route.

And, since they are storing the results in S3, you might just put your source docs in S3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to upload the local files on an online server where paperplane API can access them. Alternatively, you can try switching to another vendor which allows converting raw HTML to PDF like [pdfmark.com](https://pdfmark.com)

Disclaimer: I am the creator of PDFMark.